# Integrate $\int \frac {\sin (2x)}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Integrate 
$$\int \frac {\sin (2x)}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2} \,dx$$

My Attempt:
$$=\int \frac {\sin (2x)}{(\sin x + \cos x)^2} \,dx$$
$$=\int \frac {2\sin x \cos x}{(\sin x+ \cos x)^2} \,dx$$
Dividing the numerator and denominator by $\cos^2 x$
$$=\int \frac {2\tan x}{(1+\tan x)^2} \,dx$$

Comment: Based off your last integral. Try multiplying and dividing by $\sec^2(x)$ and let $u=\tan(x)$.

Comment: Try to avoid `\dfrac` or `\displaystyle` in titles (see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles) post).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac {\sin (2x)}{(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2} dx
&=\int \frac {2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)(1+\tan(x))^2} dx\\
&=\int\frac {2\tan(x)}{(1+\tan(x))^2} dx\\
&=\int\left(1-\frac {1+\tan^2(x)}{(1+\tan(x))^2}\right) dx\\
&=x+\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)}+c.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int\frac{\sin(2x)}{(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2}dx=\int\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)}dx\tag{1}$$ $$=\int\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)+1-1}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)+1}dx=\int dx-\int\frac{dx}{\sin(2x)+1}=x-\int\frac{1-\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}dx\tag{2}$$ $$=x-\int\sec^2(2x)dx+\int\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}dx\tag{3}$$

Enforce the substitution $u=\cos(2x)$ on the second integral so that $du=-2\sin(2x)dx$.

$(1):\text{Recall}\space\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)\space\text{and}\space(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$

$(2):$ $\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(2x)+1}=\frac{\left(\sin(2x)+1\right)-1}{\sin(2x)+1}=\frac{\sin(2x)+1}{\sin(2x)+1}-\frac{1}{\sin(2x)+1}=1-\frac{1}{1+\sin(2x)}\cdot\frac{1-\sin(2x)}{1-\sin(2x)}$

$(3):$ For $\int\sec^2(2x)dx$, let $t=2x\implies dx=\frac{dt}{2}\implies\int \sec^2(2x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\sec^2(t)dt$

Then $$I=x-\int \sec^2(2x)dx-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{u^2}=\boxed{x-\frac{1}{2}\tan(2x)+\frac{1}{2}\sec(2x)+C}$$

Answer (score 2):

From your last step,

Let, $tanx = t, \ sec^2xdx = dt \ , (1+tan^2x)dx = dt$

$dx = \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$

$I = \int{\frac{2tdt}{(1+t^2)(1+t)^2}}$

Applying partial fractions,

$\frac{2t}{(1+t^2)(1+t)^2} = \frac{1}{1+t^2} - \frac{1}{(t+1)^2}$

$I = \int{\bigg[\frac{1}{1+t^2} - \frac{1}{(t+1)^2}}\bigg]dt = tan^{-1}t + \frac{1}{(t+1)} + c$

$I = x +\frac{1}{tanx+1}+c$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}\int \frac{\sin (2 x)}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2} d x 
= & \int \frac{\sin (2 x)}{1+\sin (2 x)} d x \\
= & \int\left(1-\frac{1}{1+\sin (2 x)}\right) d x \\
= & x-\int \frac{1}{1+\sin (2 x)} \cdot \frac{1-\sin (2 x)}{1-\sin (2 x)} d x \\
= & x-\int \frac{1-\sin (2 x)}{\cos ^2(2 x)} d x \\
= & x-\int\left[\sec ^2(2 x)-\tan (2 x) \sec (2 x)\right] d x \\
= & x-\frac{1}{2}[\tan (2 x)-\sec (2 x)]+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \int\frac{sin(2x)dx}{(sinx+cosx)^{2}}$

$sin(2x)=(sinx+cosx)^{2}-1$

$\displaystyle sinx+cosx=\sqrt{2}cos(x-\frac{\pi}{4})$

$\displaystyle y=x-\frac{\pi}{4}\Rightarrow dy=dx$

$\displaystyle \int\frac{sin(2x)dx}{(sinx+cosx)^{2}}=\int(1-\frac{1}{2cos^{2}y})dy$

$\displaystyle tan(y)=z\Rightarrow dz=\frac{dy}{cos^{2}y}$

$\displaystyle\int(1-\frac{1}{2cos^{2}y})dy=y-\frac{z}{2}+c $

$\displaystyle \int\frac{sin(2x)dx}{(sinx+cosx)^{2}}=x+\frac{1}{2}\tan{(x-\frac{\pi}{4})}+c_{1}\\\left( c_{1}=c-\frac{\pi}{4} \right)$